# Sending data from vue-select to another object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-select

I'm using vue-select to have a search with select in my vue application.
For example, when I click on an option in vue-select, it will be sent to me in another object and it will disappear after the selector.

How could I do that?
I did something like that but it's not ok

```
Selector
 <v-select 
  v-model="value" 
  :options="dataTags" 
  multiple 
  @click="onAdd()"
 placeholder="Select your data">
</v-select>
```

Js

```
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        dataTags: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },

    data() {
       return {
           value: '',
           Items: {
               selected_items: []
           }
       }
    }, 

    methods: {
        onAdd() {
            this.Items.selected_items.push(this.value);
            this.value = '';
   
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And data tags are just an array of those tags, nothing special.
It is based on an id and tag.
So how can I proceed to send the selected items to a new object and make them disappear from the selector?
Can I hide them in some way?

Answer (score 0):

`vue-select` emits an event called `input` which can give you the selected value. See this section of the documentation, under "Event: input" https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#getting-and-setting

It would be something like this then:

```html
 <v-select 
  v-model="value" 
  :options="dataTags" 
  multiple 
  @input="onAdd"
 placeholder="Select your data">
</v-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try filtering the options using a computed property:

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentlySelected: null,
    options: ['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc'],
    usedOptions: []
  },
  methods: {
    select(value) {
      this.usedOptions.push(value)
      this.currentlySelected = null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredOptions() {
      return this.options.filter(option => !this.usedOptions.includes(option))
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vue-select/dist/vue-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@3.13.2/dist/vue-select.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-select v-model="currentlySelected" :options="filteredOptions" @input="select"></v-select>
  already used: {{usedOptions}}
</div>
```